# Remote connection to software not working when UWF is enabled due to firewall

Tags: windows, networking, firewall, uwf

I'm running Windows 10 Enterprise LTSC (version 10.0.17763). I've setup everything I need and I'm configuring UWF filters. I enabled protection for `C:` volume, and added a couple of exclusions for:

- allowing write on my app folder in `C:\Program Files\CustomApp` (for updates)
- allowing write on the user's "User" Documents folder `C:\Users\User\Documents\` (custom app logs, ...)
- allowing network interfaces edit

Here are the settings extracted from command `uwfmgr get-config`

```
VOLUME SETTINGS
Volume bbac04fb-9c1e-4b48-8220-5b5b315a37af [C:]
    Volume state:     Protected
    Volume ID:        bbac04fb-9c1e-4b48-8220-5b5b315a37af

    File Exclusions:
Current Session Exclusions for Volume bbac04fb-9c1e-4b48-8220-5b5b315a37af [C:]
    C:\Program Files\CustomApp
    C:\Users\User\Documents\

REGISTRY EXCLUSIONS
    HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces
    HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nsi
```

My custom app runs a WebSocket server that listen to port 8080. I added a firewall inbound rule to allow all incoming requests for the app.

When the firewall is enabled and UWF filer is disabled, I can connect to my app from another PC. When UWF is enabled, the connection fails.

If I completely disable the firewall, I can connect to the app both when UWF manager is enabled or disabled.

What UWF configuration am I missing to have the firewall working as expected with UWF filtering enabled?